# Getting 401 error when using API Key to Retrieve Gmail inbox contents via list endpoint

Tags: c#, google-cloud-platform, gmail-api

I am trying to add some API tests for our application that validate that a message is sent out and eventually received in Gmail. I went ahead and added an API key for my email in the Google Cloud Services developer console and created the following code.

The Client.cs class is just an example I found online that I tweaked and made work with our endpoints (maybe this type of strategy wont work with Gmail API?)

Enpoints.cs is just the class to return the URL. Im also including the key as an optional parameter

Test.cs just contains a segment of how I am calling the endpoint and getting the 401 Unauthorized error

Are we able to use the list endpoint to get the contents of a gmail inbox by using an API Key?

**Client.cs**

```
public enum Command {
    GET,
    POST,
    PUT,
    DELETE }

namespace Project{
    public class Client
    {

        public string endPoint { get; set; }
        public Command execute { get; set; }
        public string contentType { get; set; }
        public string postData { get; set; }
        public string encoded = "";

        // Basic Client
        public Client()
        {
            endPoint = "";
            execute = Command.GET;
            contentType = "application/JSON";
            postData = "";
            encoded = System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes("email@gmail.com"
+ ":" + "mypass"));
        }

        // Basic Request
        public string Request(string parameters)
        {
            var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(parameters);
            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded);
            request.Method = execute.ToString();
            request.ContentLength = 0;
            request.ContentType = contentType;

            if (postData != "")
            {
                request.SendChunked = true;
                request.ContentType = "application/json";

                using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
                {
                    string json = postData;

                    streamWriter.Write(json);
                }
            }

            using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {
                var responseValue = string.Empty;

                if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    var message = String.Format("Failed: Received HTTP {0}", response.StatusCode);
                    Console.WriteLine(message);
                    //throw new ApplicationException(message);
                }

                using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    if (responseStream != null)
                        using (var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                        {
                            responseValue = reader.ReadToEnd();
                        }
                }

                return responseValue;
            }
        }
    }


}
```

**Endpoints.cs**

```
namespace Project
{
    class Endpoints
    {

        // Class to store URLs for Gmail Integrations
        public static class Gmail
        {
            // Class to interface with Gmail Messages
            public static class Messages
            {
                // Retrieve Messsages (List)
                public static string List(string userId)
                {
                    return "https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/" + userId + "/messages?key=mykey";
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

**Test.cs**

```
// Prepare the Client
Client client = new Client();

// Get the Response
client.execute = Command.GET;
var response = client.Request(Endpoints.Gmail.Messages.List("email@gmail.com"));

// Print Response
Console.WriteLine(response);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Because Gmail includes personal|user data, you will need to provide a facility for the specific user to permit access using OAuth2. There's a facility within Workspace for [domain-wide delegation of a Service Account](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation) that permits the Service Account to operate on your users' behalf.

Google's [APIs Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer) is very useful.

For [Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest), you can interact with e.g. [`users.messages.list`](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/list?apix_params=%7B%22userId%22%3A%22me%22%7D) in the browser.

Google provides auto-generated API Client Libraries for every service in 8 languages. Here's [Gmail API Client Library for .NET](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/dotnet). I **strongly encourage you to use Google SDKs** to avoid dealing with the APIs' types, auth, logging etc. directly. As you've seen, this can be challenging, unnecessarily duplicates work (best left to Google) and increases the scope of your security audit.

If you look at the HTTP example from APIs Explorer. You will see that the HTTPS request must include an `Authorization` header with a value of `Bearer [SOME-ACCESS-TOKEN]`. The Access Token will be provided to you by Google's OAuth2 endpoint.

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/list?apix_params=%7B%22userId%22%3A%22me%22%7D&apix=true

I was unable to find the link to a good overview of API keys and why you should avoid using them to authenticate. API keys are easily obtained and are a bearer credential (i.e. you don't want them to be easily obtained). Generally (!) an API key is used to associate requests with a specific Google project for billing purposes. They should not be used to authenticate users. See [API keys](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys)

Comment: Thank you for this - when I go to also add the OAuth id, it asks for an Application Type.. I am not sure what to enter here. My goal here was for this to just be a headless test, I am not really running through an application. I just want to retrieve what's in the inbox and validate the message exists.

Comment: You're welcome! For your follow-up questions, please consider submitting these as new questions. Your code **is** an application and needs an identity.

Comment: Well its just C# code and I am using NUnit.. Would I just specify it as a Desktop app or are you saying this might not really matter then for my purposes?

Comment: I've taken the the time to answer your question. You have follow-up questions and I don't wish to spend more time on this question. Everything is well-documented. Please consider reading the docs and asking follow-up questions: https://developers.google.com/workspace/guides/auth-overview

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who might stumble upon this, it turns out there really is no easy way to do this with GMail. This post does describe a way to do it, however with the OAuth2 authentication, you will need to login using a browser popup which means no headless API tests..

https://www.swtestacademy.com/gmail-api-test-automation/

I ended up using this product, https://testmail.app/, which is super affordable and lightweight and works great if you are just trying to do some simple email validations.